# apache redirect port from 8000 to 80

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to redirect the URL from http://10.11.12.221:8000/ to http://10.11.12.221/index.html from port 8000 to 80. I did the following in `ports.conf` file but didn't work.

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000

<VirtualHost *:8000>
    redirect / http://10.11.12.221/index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

I also try the following but doesn't work too.

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName 10.11.12.221
  ServerAlias 10.11.12.221
  ProxyPass / http://10.11.12.221:80/index.html
  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.11.12.221:80/index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

any ideas why? Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Add logs to the question.  Are the proxy modules loaded?

Comment: Proxying != redirecting. What are you trying to achieve exactly? aka, what should the final URL look like?

Comment: If the users go to http://10.11.12.221:8000/ in the browser, I just want to redirect from http://10.11.12.221:8000/ to http://10.11.12.221/index.html